# Prove that every $A \subset X$ satisfies $Y \smallsetminus f(A) \subset f(X\smallsetminus A)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose that $f$ is surjective. I need to prove that every $A \subset X$ satisfies $Y \smallsetminus f(A) \subset f(X\smallsetminus A)$.

Here's what I have so far:

I suppose $y\in Y\smallsetminus f(A)$. Since $f$ is surjective, there exists an $x \in X$ such that $f(x)=y$ by definition.

We also know that $y \not\in f(A)$. Is it possible at this point to say that $x \not\in A$? I wasn't sure because there is no mention of $f$ being invertible.

Let me know if I'm on the right track for this problem.

Comment: Yes, $x \notin A$, since if $x$ were in $A$, then $y = f(x) \in f(A)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as your next step you can conclude that $x \notin A$.  If you want justification then a short little proof by contradiction will work: *Suppose $x \in A$.  Then, by definition, $y = f(x) \in f(A)$.  But this contradicts $y \notin f(A)$.  Thus the assumption is wrong, we must have $x \notin A$.*