# Proving $Y\setminus f(A)\subset f(X\setminus A)$, for all $A$, if and only if $f$ is surjective

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$.

A necessary and sufficient condition that $Y\setminus f(A) \subset f(X\setminus A)$ for all  $A\subset  X$ is that $f$ is surjective.

I'm having trouble starting the proof when assuming $Y\setminus f(A) \subset f(X\setminus A)$ for all $A\subset  X$ and proving that its surjective. I understand that the conclusion to the proof is the definition for surjectivity: $\forall b\in Y$,  $\exists a\in X$  such that $f(a)=b$.

Answer (score 1):

**$f$ surjective $\implies Y \setminus f(A) \subset f(X \setminus A)$ for all $A \subset X$**

Suppose $f$ is surjective. Take $y \in Y \setminus f(A)$, $f$ is onto therefore exists $x \in X$ sucht that $f(x)=y$, but $y \in Y \setminus f(A) \implies x \not \in A \implies y \in f(X \setminus A).$

---

**Viceversa:**

Suppose $Y \setminus f(A) \subset f(X \setminus A) \space \forall A \subset X$. Setting $A= \emptyset$ we have that $Y \subset f(X) \implies Y=f(X)$.
$$\text{or}$$
Take $A = \{x \in X | f(x) \ne y \}$, we have that $f(A) \subset Y \setminus \{y\}$ so $y \in Y\setminus f(A) \subset f(X \setminus A)$ therefore $y$ is in the image of $X \setminus A$ under $f$.